# Why I cannot add data into Firebase in this way?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a project which is concerned about Firebase, I have tried to upload the data to the Firebase as the code in the tutorial from the Firebase website:

```
    // An index to track Ada's memberships
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      // Index Ada's groups in her profile
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

and I follow this structure to write my own data structure, which looks like this:

```
func pushUser() {
        let username = self.username
        let userid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        let userInfo : [String : Any] = ["username" : username,
            "userID" : userid,
            "sggestedRoutes" : "",
            "myTracedRoutes" : "",
            "routes": {
                "usualInfo" : true,
                "calcuInfo" : true
        }
    ]

        let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        userRef.child("user").childByAutoId().setValue(userInfo)
    }
```

in Swift3, but the debugger says the nested routes{} is not correct, I am quite confused about this, could anyone give me a hint on this?

Kind regards

---

After received the advice, I make some change on the code, but it is still not working on the Route part:(

```
func pushUser() {
        let username = self.username
        let userid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        let userInfo : [String : Any] =
            ["username" : username,
             "userID" : userid,
             "sggestedRoutes" : "",
             "uploadedRoutes" : "",
             "myTracedRoutes" : "",
             ["Routes":
                ["usualInfo" : true,
                 "calcuInfo" : true]
             ]
            ]
        let userRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        userRef.child("user").childByAutoId().setValue(userInfo)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the routes as ["routes":  ["usualInfo": true, "calcuInfo": true]]

Don't forget the correct closures for both children "user info" and "routes"

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply, but this one also not working, xCode will inform you that there should be a ":" in the interval, I have no idea still :(